# Simplest way for a clean uninstall/install of vim with python support

Tags: vimscript-python

I have vim that is compiled with an outdated version of python (3.4).

I have install python into a local directory and verified it works properly:

```
$ which python3.7
/usr/local/bin/python3.7
```

What would be the simplest way to uninstall and re-install vim that is linked to this 3.7 library?

In the past I have only used:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim
```

I'm hoping I could pass something like:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim option--with-python3-config-dir=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Comment: This is not a situation, that would occur with a distribution, because you get what is packaged for. If you really want to have different "compile flags" (or linked against other libraries) you have to compile your own version (and this is not very hard with Vim).

Comment: I usually compile Vim myself to make sure it has all the features that I want.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt sort of...the manual compile I did with all the flags but could never get it to work. The only ways that would actually compile with python3.4 (and never 3.7) were using apt-get vim or apt-get vim-gtk (and even with that I had to re-link to the correct vim binary).